# Entity framework doesn't save data entries in database

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, savechanges, windows

At first I should mention that this problem only occurs in windows forms applications and the same program in web mode for example with MVC3 works perfect.

Some days ago I wrote a very simple windows form program using Visual studio 2010 ultimate with a SQL Express database. I added the database by choosing Add > New item > Service-Based database and an entity data model based on this database in same way. I used Entity framework for adding some new records to tables. I had done such thing with VS 2008 SP1 before with no problem so I did the same. The program compiled and ran with no errors and I entered some new data. after exiting the program I came back to the database and nothing was happened. None of information I had entered had been saved.
I debug the program step by step and everything was alright.
The code below is related to a very simple program with mentioned problem. Database has one table (book):

```
namespace Book
{
    public partial class BookForm : Form
    {
        BookDatabaseEntities db = new BookDatabaseEntities();

        public BookForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Book bookToCreate = new Book();

            bookToCreate.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            bookToCreate.Title = titleTextBox.Text;

            db.Books.AddObject(bookToCreate);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I'll be very grateful if anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

.................

After editing:

```
namespace Book
{
    public partial class BookForm : Form
    {
        //BookDatabaseEntities db = new BookDatabaseEntities();

        public BookForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var db = new BookDatabaseEntities();
            var bookToCreate = db.Books.CreateObject();

            //Book bookToCreate = new Book();

            bookToCreate.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            bookToCreate.Title = titleTextBox.Text;

            db.AcceptAllChanges();
            db.Books.AddObject(bookToCreate);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to replace "new db.Books();" with "db.Books.CreateObject();"

Comment: Make sure that you are checking correct database.

Comment: @Davide: I used CreateObject as you said but the problem still exists.

Comment: @Ladislav: Yes I'm sure. this simple program has only one database file

Comment: show us your latest code please

Comment: I Added it at the end of my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after lots of searching and asking I found the solution in MSDN forums thanks to *Patrice Scribe*
You can see it
[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Monoloox.After long searching finally I got Answer from you.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
db.Attach(bookToCreate);
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Edit:**

I have this code in a class library (my DAL) in production and it works fine:

```
using (var dbContext = new DbEntities())
    {
        var job = dbContext.RiskToolJob.CreateObject();

        job.AnalysisDataID = analysisDataID;

        job.JobRmsAnalysisID = RMSAnalysisID;
        job.UserName = userName;

        job.JobCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;

        dbContext.RiskToolJob.AddObject(job);

        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return job.DataId;
    }
```

notice that in fact I do not assign the PK (**DataId**) because it will be assigned by the database, i return it to the caller so who has invoked the save method gets to know the auto generated ID, in case it needs it.

Comment: Dear Davide ... I did what you said but the result is still the same. I think the problem is about SaveChanges() method because after executing the (db.Books.AddObject) or (db.Books.Attach) the object has been added into the ObjectStateManager and it seems that SaveChanges is unable to save it into database. However it reports no error during the entering process

Comment: One another thing .. As I said when I write the same code in web form or MVC it works without this problem. It happens only in windows form apps and I don't know why.

Comment: Davide why would db.Attach help? From the MS docs - "db.Attach is used to repopulate a context with an entity that is known to already exist in the database. SaveChanges will therefore not attempt to insert an attached entity into the database because it is assumed to already be there"