# Entity Framework isn't saving data to database in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml

I'm developing a POS in WPF. 
For CRUD operations, I'm using Entity Framework.

1. Created a WPF View ProductADD
   [Product Add View Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKvKk.png)
2. Created a Class ProductController in Controller Folder
3. Made object of Entity Framework in ProductController Class [ProductController Calss Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmTd8.png)
4. Created a method: SaveProduct(Product product) which is taking product object as argument and saving it to database using EF.
5. And From Xaml.Cs I'm calling ProductController Class's Saveproduct method and sending the new product data to it.

   ```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        ProductController pc = new ProductController();
        PRODUCT product = new PRODUCT();

        product.PRODUCT_NAME = Product_Name.Text.ToString();
        product.UNITPRICE = Convert.ToInt32(Unit_Price.Text.ToString());
        product.CATEGORY_Id = 1;
        pc.SaveProduct(product);

        MessageBox.Show("Product Added Successfully");

        this.Close();
   }
   ```

And in ProductController the following code is updating the database

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PizzaLounge.Models;

namespace PizzaLounge.Controllers 
{
 public class ProductController 
 {
  PizzaLoungeEntities db = new PizzaLoungeEntities();
  public void SaveProduct(PRODUCT product) 
  {
   db.PRODUCTs.Add(product);
   db.SaveChanges();
  }
 }
}
```

6. The code executes successfully but it doesn't save the product in database. P.S. I have used db.savechanges().

Am I missing something or using wrong approach to update database?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking into the right database?

Comment: Show code for this method `pc.SaveProduct(product)`

Comment: update ur question with model of the table and saveproduct method

Comment: Show code of actual saving operation into database like `pc.SaveProduct(product);`

Comment: the depicted code doesn't contain savechanges. Pls show us what the saveproduct do

Comment: pls do look for the result of this operation `int result = db.savechanges()`

Comment: In your SaveProduct(product) method check you have do the followings:
1. Get the dbContext
2. Add the product to the context - dbContext.Products.Add(product);
3. Save the changes to the context - dbContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: I have updated the question and has shown the saveproduct(product) code!

Comment: @Jcl yes I'm pretty sure because I'm using EF for this that is linked with actual database.

Comment: @ARUN What kind of error? I'm not getting any kind of error. It's just writing data into database.

Comment: test it, read data using the same context, and see if it work, then we can rectify this

Comment: Check the return value from SaveChanges.

Comment: Yet another instance of localdb confusion.

Comment: surround savechanges with try/catch and i am sure you will find it is failing, output the stacktrace. probably havnt defined Primary Key properly is Catagory_ID a foreign key? does Category 1 exist?

Comment: Could you post your connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using |DataDirectory| in your connection string. If debugging in Visual Studio, the database you are using is in the bin/debug folder. 
Unfortunately if you look at the db through Server Explorer it has a different connection string so you don't see the changes.

Also if the database property "Copy to Output directory" is set to Copy Always then every time you debug you will overwrite your db and you won't see the data you added. You can check if this is happening by using a new db context in the same debug session where you add the records. If the new context can get the records from the db then you know they must be being written (as well as the other checks listed in the comments)

This can be fixed by changing Copy To Output Directory to Never Copy or Copy If Newer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using **mdf file attached to your project** so your problem is like this question

[Attaching database to my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028246/attaching-database-to-my-project)

You are saving data to database that is in **bin\debug** folders ,and then you see the mdf file that is in your project folder and you don't see the data .

change your connection string from **DataDirectory** to 
absolute path to the project database file. When deploying, just change it back to **|DataDirectory|**

Comment: Tried your method but it's still not writing to db. db.SaveChanges() returns 1 but at backend it's not writing to database.

Comment: Are using database that attached to `local sql server` or you have added `mdf file` to your project?

Answer (score -1):

How did you checked that the products haven't been added, from db.PRODUCTs or from the Database Explorer?

Maybe you just need to dispose your context, change your ProductController for something like:

```
using(var db = new PizzaLoungeEntities()){
   db.PRODUCTs.Add(product);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or to dispose ProductController after you finish to use it.

Comment: From Database Explorer after refreshing it.

Comment: I tried this method but it's still not writing to database!

Comment: Did you try this: [entity-framework-doesnt-save-data-entries-in-database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329167/entity-framework-doesnt-save-data-entries-in-database)?

Comment: changes are saved with savechanges dont need dispose to update